# Pandas all cells which length <2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to acquire all rows in Dataframe where if the length of any cloumu shorter than 2.

For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["a","ab",""],"col2":["bc","abc", "a"]})

   col1 col2
0    a   bc
1   ab  abc
2         a
```

How to get this output:

```py
   col1 col2
0    a   bc
2         a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `stack` to reshape then using `str.len` compute the length and create boolean mask with `lt` + `any`:

```
df[df.stack().str.len().lt(2).any(level=0)]
```

---

```
  col1 col2
0    a   bc
2         a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `len()` method of the pandas Series :

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col][df[col].str.len() < 3]
df = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension could help here :

```
df.loc[[not any(len(word) > 2 for word in entry)
        for entry in df.to_numpy()]
       ]

        col1    col2
   0    a       bc
   2            a
```